# Is needed declare class atributtes?

Tags: php, oop

**Declaring**

```
class MyClass
{

  public $someVar;

  function __construct()
  {
    $this->someVar = 'some value';
  }
}
```

**Not declaring**

```
class MyClass
{
  function __construct()
  {
    $this->someVar = 'some value';
  }
}
```

The both ways works but I would to know if theres a difference about performance or even pattern.

Comment: If you don't declare class properties, then any new properties you create dynamically will always be public (you can't control visibility)

Comment: If you don't declare class properties, they can't be hinted by an IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. Cause when you declare attributes in class declaration you've got net pros:

1. Looking on declaration other developer can find which properties he
   can use ( if you don't want to allow other developers use them -
   declare them as protected/ private see below )
2. You can set
   visibility flags manually - best practice set private by default and
       change access level only if need ( better use geters/seters)
3. You and other developers got autocomplete in IDE